# Detecting Advanced privacy settings in IE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

At the moment I'm using Modernizr to detect if the client is blocking cookies and provide warnings if it's going to prevent them doing something i.e login or add to cart.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/cookies.js

However I've found that if you use the Advanced privacy settings to block cookies this is not detected so the user doesn't get any warning and the site will appear to be broken.

I can't seem to find anything that suggests any way around this.

Comment: Why not attempt to set a cookie, and then fetch it.  If you get it back, cookies work, if not, they are disabled/blocked.

Answer (score 2):

The Modernizr test is a purely client-side test. If IE's settings fool that test, it seems like you'll need to set a cookie in your main response, then do an ajax call and see if the cookie went back to the server. If it did, cookies aren't blocked; if it didn't, they are.

This also has the advantage that it's an end-to-end test: It doesn't matter *where* the cookie was blocked (the browser, a proxy, etc.), it'll tell you whether cookies currently work for that user in that environment with your site.